# How to change cell label font size?

Tags: swift, uilabel, swift4, uifont

I'd like to change the font size on a table cell label. The font face should stay whatever it is. I'm using

> System - System

since that is what shows in the Xcode interface.

I'm doing the following in

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

but nothing is happening. Any suggestions how this should be done?

```
cell.labelName.font = UIFont(name: "System - System", size: CGFloat(16))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the system font like this.

```
cell.labelName.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
```

`UIFont(name:size:)` returns nil if font is not available and thats why nothing happening. I don't think "System - System" is a valid font name.